# Get current month record using LIKE key word

Tags: sql-server, date

I try to get selected the current month data by using SQL Server LIKE but it not get the any result. My when I run same code in my SQL it get the original result. What is error of my query? This query I want to run in SQL Server.

```
SELECT EnrolledID, Date, Time 
FROM dbo.view_attendance
WHERE Date LIKE '2019-08%'
ORDER BY Date,Time;
```

Date in the SQL Server database date is something like that `2019-08-14 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: Where format(date, ‘yyyy-MM’) = ‘2019-08’, but better to just use date parts: year(date) = 2019 and month(date) = 8

Comment: What datatype is your "Date" column?

Comment: DATETIME format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MySql** does implicit conversions between data types in expressions like your case:

```
Date LIKE '2019-08%'
```

so **MySql** converts `Date` to `varchar` and the expression returns a valid result because both operands are treated as `varchar`s.
You can find more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

**SQL Server** does **not** do this, so you must **explicitly** do the conversion or use a function like:

```
WHERE FORMAT(Date, 'yyyy-MM') = '2019-08'
```

Comment: I honestly dread to think what a clause with `FORMAT` is going to do for performance. `FORMAT` is already a really slow function to use in the `SELECT`; having it is the `WHERE` for a boolean expression on the value of a column is going to be a killer.

Comment: Format() is just an example of a function that can be used. In any case the problem is that either Date must be coverted to VARCHAR or compared to datetime data type.

Comment: Yes, but converting the submitted value (`'2019-08'` in this case) to a date/time data type is by far the right choice.

Comment: Convertion is still a function like process. If you have a date literal like '20190801' to compare against the column Date then yes it is better.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you have asked for a `LIKE`, I would recommend using the following format:

```
SELECT [EnrolledID]
    , [Date]
    , [Time]
FROM dbo.view_attendance 
WHERE [Date] >= '20190801' and [Date] < '20190901'
ORDER BY [Date], [Time];
```

Although there is no syntax error in the case of using `LIKE` over `DATETIME` columns, I would recommend using `LIKE` only when trying to parse `STRING` values, in search for a certain pattern.

`LIKE` will not work with `DATETIME` columns and will not return results. If your column is of type `DATETIME` then I recommend using the above method.

Comment: problem is i want to get the current month.current month get by $currentMonth= date('Y-m'); in php

Comment: it will return 2019-08.

Comment: that why try to use the LIKE key word

Comment: This is definitely the best solution here, as it's SARGable. if you want (have) to pass a value like `'2019-08'` then fix the value to be `date`: `WHERE [Date] >= @YourParam + '01' AND [Date] < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@YourParam + '01')`

Comment: @nipun you can simply use `[Date] >= DATEFROMPARTS(?, ?, 1) AND [Date] < DATEFROMPARTS(?, ? + 1, 1)`... use PHP code to replace ? with `date("Y") `and `date("m")`. This **is** the correct approach.

Comment: thank you bro advised .i will try that .much appreciate your help

Comment: So, I was 1h in a meeting and missed this thread. Based from your original question, the solution I provided was purely SQL (T-SQL / MSSQL) related, since there weren't any pointers to PHP. Even if you add PHP to the scenario, if you're going to solve this problem with T-SQL, then this is still the approach I recommend (for the reasons Larnu also mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

if [Date] column is DateTime Type, try this :

```
declare @currentMonth int = datepart(MONTH,GETDATE())
declare @currentYear int = datepart(YEAR,GETDATE())

SELECT [EnrolledID]
    , [Date]
    , [Time]
FROM dbo.view_attendance 
WHERE DATEPART(year,[Date]) = @currentYear And DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]) = @currentMonth
ORDER BY [Date], [Time];
```

or this:

```
SELECT [EnrolledID]
    , [Date]
    , [Time]
FROM dbo.view_attendance 
WHERE DATEPART(year,[Date]) = datepart(YEAR,GETDATE()) And DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]) =  datepart(MONTH,GETDATE())
ORDER BY [Date], [Time];
```